# can't resize MovieClip ActionScript 2

Tags: image, actionscript, resize, runtime, actionscript-2

I created a MovieClip object and i load a image.But then I want to resize it. I tried _width and _height but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
var movieClip:MovieClip;
var pic:String = "http://pro-game.comyr.com/mo.jpg";
movieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("movieClip", 0);
movieClip.loadMovie(pic);

//this doesn't work
movieClip._height = 100;
movieClip._width = 100;
```

Please if someone can help I will be very glad :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are using the  action script 2.0 ,try this code which is in action script3.0

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ldr_complete);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("http://pro-game.comyr.com/mo.jpg");
function ldr_complete(evt:Event):void
{

   var bmp:Bitmap= ldr.content as Bitmap;
   var img = new Bitmap(bmp.bitmapData);
   img.x =20;
   img.y = 20;
   img.width=500;
   img.height=500;
   addChild(img);
}
```

Comment: If u want to change anything in your answer, just [edit] the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pic:String = "http://pro-game.comyr.com/mo.jpg";
this.createEmptyMovieClip("movieClip", this.getNextHighestDepth());
movieClip.beginFill(0xFF0000);
movieClip.moveTo(10, 10);
movieClip.lineTo(100, 10);
movieClip.lineTo(100, 100);
movieClip.lineTo(10, 100);
movieClip.lineTo(10, 10);
movieClip.endFill();

this.movieClip.loadMovie(pic);
this.movieClip._width = this.movieClip._height = 20;
```

Trying to set width and height for an empty movieClip will always returns 0.

Comment: But it does not :P Anyway I found a salution :-) I created a MovieClip in design view and I load image there later on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

this code will be work in ActionScript 2.0. Please try it any enjoy...

```
var movieClip:MovieClip;
var pic:String = "http://pro-game.comyr.com/mo.jpg";
movieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("movieClip", 0);
movieClip.loadMovie(pic);


movieClip.onLoadComplete = function (targetMC)
{   
   targetMC._parent._width = 100;
   targetMC._parent._height = 100;
}
```